# Powershell TCP Send Entire File

Tags: c#, powershell, tcp

I'm trying to send a file over TCP sockets, but it only is sending the first 1024 bytes, I have tried to look at c# code but could not figure it out.  The file is in binary format if that helps  Can some one let me know what I am missing?

**client**

```
$test=[io.file]::ReadAllBytes("c:\test");
$socket = New-Object net.sockets.tcpclient('192.168.1.202',8080);
$stream = $socket.GetStream();
$stream.write($test,0,$test.Length);
$writer.flush();
$socket.close()
```

**Server**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'socket'
begin
  server = TCPServer.open(8080)
  client = server.accept
  recv_length = 1024
  out_put = ''
  while (tmp = client.recv(recv_length))
    out_put += tmp
    break if tmp.length < recv_length
  end
  File.open("test.txt",'w') {|f| f.write(out_put)}
  server.close
end
```

Side note if i try to Base64 encode $test it has a fit and doesn't even try to send any data over.

EDIT:

**Below works**.  I changed the server to gets instead of recv now it just pulls everything and waits for the client to close the socket.

**Client**

```
$test=[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([io.file]::ReadAllBytes("c:\test"));
$socket = New-Object net.sockets.tcpclient('172.26.4.26',8080);
$stream = $socket.GetStream();
$writer = new-object System.IO.StreamWriter($stream);
$buffer = new-object System.Byte[] 1024;
$writer.WriteLine($test);
$socket.close()
```

**Server**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'socket'
require 'base64'
begin
  server = TCPServer.open(8080)
  client = server.accept
  out_put = client.gets()
  File.open("test","w") {|f| f.write(Base64.decode64(out_put))}
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Client**

```
$test=[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([io.file]::ReadAllBytes("c:\test"));
$socket = New-Object net.sockets.tcpclient('172.26.4.26',8080);
$stream = $socket.GetStream();
$writer = new-object System.IO.StreamWriter($stream);
$buffer = new-object System.Byte[] 1024;
$writer.WriteLine($test);
$socket.close()
```

**Server**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'socket'
require 'base64'
begin
  server = TCPServer.open(8080)
  client = server.accept
  out_put = client.gets()
  File.open("test","w") {|f| f.write(Base64.decode64(out_put))}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess, but it may be related to the server code?!

```
 recv_length = 1024
```

EDIT:

You could try a close of the stream, maybe that is the problem?!

```
$stream.write($test,0,$test.Length);
$stream.close();
$writer.flush();
```

Comment: unfortunately not the while loop will take all the data and then write it to a file once it is all gathered.  But as a test I have already tried to bump it up to 2048 and it only gets 1024 so it has to be something with the powershell (client side).

Comment: Closing the stream didn't change the output either.